# Call function and pass parameter over url PHP

Tags: php

This is my PHP script:

```
<?php

function myFunc($param1)
{
echo $param1;
}

if(isset($_GET['action'])){
    if(function_exists($_GET['action'])) {    
        $_GET['action']();
    }
}

?>
```

Now I want call this function from other php and pass parameter:

> http://localhost/data.php?action=myFunc

How to pass parameter to myFunc through url?

Comment: What are you trying to echo? You aren't passing anything to the function.

Comment: You also don't need 2 `if`s, `if(isset($_GET['action']) && function_exists($_GET['action'])){`.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php

Comment: Be careful with this approach it is very insecure!

Comment: Using this, anyone can call _any_ function, include any of PHP's built in functions. You should have a white list of allowed functions or things can go south pretty fast.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is most certainly wrong and **insecure** (imagine what would happen if you tried calling it with `action=unlink&param=somefile.php`), but you could do something like:

With URL: `http://localhost/data.php?action=myFunc&param=123`

```
<?php

function myFunc($param1)
{
echo $param1;
}

if(isset($_GET['action'])){
    if(function_exists($_GET['action'])) {    
        $_GET['action']($_GET['param']);
    }
}
```